# Extracting table data from html with python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new with python and beautifulsopu lib. I have tried many things, but no luck.

My html code could be like:

```
<form method = "post" id="FORM1" name="FORM1">
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0 align="center" bgcolor="#cccccc">
   <tr>

    <td class="producto"><b>Club</b><br>

       <input value="CLUB TENIS DE MESA PORTOBAIL" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtClub" size="60" maxlength="55">
     </td> 
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="producto"><b>Nombre Equipo</b><br>
    <input value="C.T.M. PORTOBAIL" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtNomEqu" size="100" maxlength="80">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="producto"><b>Telefono fijo</b><br>
       <input value="63097005534" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtTelf" size="15" maxlength="10">
     </td
```

and I need JUST to take what is within <"b"><"/b"> and its "input value" .

Many thanks!!

Comment: You might want to post some of what you have tried, as that is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [find()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) your form by id, then [find_all()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) inputs inside and get the value of `value` [attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """<form method = "post" id="FORM1" name="FORM1">
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0 align="center" bgcolor="#cccccc">
   <tr>

    <td class="producto"><b>Club</b><br>

       <input value="CLUB TENIS DE MESA PORTOBAIL" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtClub" size="60" maxlength="55">
     </td>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="producto"><b>Nombre Equipo</b><br>
    <input value="C.T.M. PORTOBAIL" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtNomEqu" size="100" maxlength="80">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="producto"><b>Telefono fijo</b><br>
       <input value="63097005534" disabled class="txtmascaraform" type="TEXT" name="txtTelf" size="15" maxlength="10">
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
form = soup.find("form", {'id': "FORM1"})
print [item.get('value') for item in form.find_all('input')]

# UPDATE for getting table cell values
table = form.find("table")
print [item.text.strip() for item in table.find_all('td')]
```

prints:

```
['CLUB TENIS DE MESA PORTOBAIL', 'C.T.M. PORTOBAIL', '63097005534']
[u'Club', u'Nombre Equipo', u'Telefono fijo']
```

Comment: and how could i get wht is within: <"b"><"/b">  ?? Many thanks!!

Comment: @juasmilla updated the answer, check it out. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful, thanks.